Reduce used space; reclaim a physical disk
I'm running Proxmox 8.2.2. Recently my lvg became corrupt ("volume group pve has insufficient free space!")
First, I tried to repair the vg:
$ sudo lvconvert --repair pve/data
Volume group "pve" has insufficient free space (2017 extents): 2077 required.

So I plugged in an extra disk and added it to the group:
$ sudo pvcreate /dev/sdj
$ sudo vgextend pve /dev/sdj

and re-ran the repair:
$ sudo lvconvert --repair pve/data
WARNING: You have not turned on protection against thin pools running out of space.
WARNING: Set activation/thin_pool_autoextend_threshold below 100 to trigger automatic extension of thin pools before they get full.
WARNING: Sum of all thin volume sizes (<884.02 GiB) exceeds the size of thin pools (<794.79 GiB).
WARNING: You have not turned on protection against thin pools running out of space.
WARNING: Set activation/thin_pool_autoextend_threshold below 100 to trigger automatic extension of thin pools before they get full.
WARNING: LV pve/data_meta2 holds a backup of the unrepaired metadata. Use lvremove when no longer required.
WARNING: New metadata LV pve/data_tmeta might use different PVs.  Move it with pvmove if required.

Now, my data is accessible. I have deleted some of what I don't need. Here's what I want to do:

Prevent this from happening again by understanding the above warnings re thin pools and putting limits in place.

Reduce the logical volume span so that I don't need the extra physical disk I just plugged in.

Remove the physical disk without damaging or risking anything in the lv.


I'm out of my depth here - I would really appreciate any insight or links to documentation so I can understand how I got myself into this mess, how I can enforce limits so I don't get into it again, and how to get myself back to a state where the lvg doesn't contain the new drive.
EDIT:
$ sudo pvdisplay
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdk3
VG Name               pve
PV Size               931.01 GiB / not usable 4.69 MiB
Allocatable           yes
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              238338
Free PE               2017
Allocated PE          236321
PV UUID               Msq2HF-K0f1-5spf-hWis-irni-vrLM-fiyq1N
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdj
VG Name               pve
PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable <1.09 MiB
Allocatable           yes
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              476932
Free PE               474855
Allocated PE          2077
PV UUID               Jl1Jkd-4PJs-uAu9-bOUb-2yEQ-dnFb-YS5RVf

$ sudo vgdisplay
--- Volume group ---
VG Name               pve
System ID
Format                lvm2
Metadata Areas        2
Metadata Sequence No  746
VG Access             read/write
VG Status             resizable
MAX LV                0
Cur LV                12
Open LV               5
Max PV                0
Cur PV                2
Act PV                2
VG Size               <2.73 TiB
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              715270
Alloc PE / Size       238398 / 931.24 GiB
Free  PE / Size       476872 / <1.82 TiB
VG UUID               cmDgdu-22V6-Tx4j-pwNG-42ZZ-vRiG-SA850C

$ sudo lvs
LV            VG  Attr       LSize    Pool Origin Data%  Meta%      Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
data          pve twi-aotz-- <794.79g             61.00  3.20
data_meta0    pve -wi-a-----    8.11g
data_meta1    pve -wi-a-----    8.11g
root          pve -wi-ao----   96.00g
swap          pve -wi-ao----    8.00g
vm-100-disk-0 pve Vwi-aotz--   32.00g data        20.35
vm-100-disk-1 pve Vwi-aotz--    4.00m data        14.06
vm-102-disk-0 pve Vwi-aotz--   10.00g data        35.51
vm-104-disk-0 pve Vwi-a-tz--    8.00g data        57.03
vm-110-disk-0 pve Vwi-a-tz--    4.00m data        14.06
vm-110-disk-1 pve Vwi-a-tz--  650.00g data        72.34
vm-110-disk-2 pve Vwi-a-tz--    4.00m data        1.56

$ sudo pvdisplay -m
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdk3
VG Name               pve
PV Size               931.01 GiB / not usable 4.69 MiB
Allocatable           yes
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              238338
Free PE               2017
Allocated PE          236321
PV UUID               Msq2HF-K0f1-5spf-hWis-irni-vrLM-fiyq1N
--- Physical Segments ---
Physical extent 0 to 2047:
  Logical volume      /dev/pve/swap
  Logical extents     0 to 2047
Physical extent 2048 to 26623:
  Logical volume      /dev/pve/root
  Logical extents     0 to 24575
Physical extent 26624 to 230089:
  Logical volume      /dev/pve/data_tdata
  Logical extents     0 to 203465
Physical extent 230090 to 232166:
  Logical volume      /dev/pve/data_meta0
  Logical extents     0 to 2076
Physical extent 232167 to 234243:
  Logical volume      /dev/pve/data_meta1
  Logical extents     0 to 2076
Physical extent 234244 to 236320:
  Logical volume      /dev/pve/data_tmeta
  Logical extents     0 to 2076
Physical extent 236321 to 238337:
  FREE
--- Physical volume ---
PV Name               /dev/sdj
VG Name               pve
PV Size               <1.82 TiB / not usable <1.09 MiB
Allocatable           yes
PE Size               4.00 MiB
Total PE              476932
Free PE               474855
Allocated PE          2077
PV UUID               Jl1Jkd-4PJs-uAu9-bOUb-2yEQ-dnFb-YS5RVf
--- Physical Segments ---
Physical extent 0 to 2076:
  FREE
Physical extent 2077 to 4153:
  Logical volume      /dev/pve/lvol1_pmspare
  Logical extents     0 to 2076
Physical extent 4154 to 476931:
  FREE


@TomYan there's enough here you should make that an answer


my lvg became corrupt ("volume group pve has insufficient free space!")

That doesn't sound like it's "corrupt", but just that the mapped size of the thin volumes reached the size of the VG
I don't know how much you know about thin pool/provisioning, but essentially it adds another "layer" on top of the VG so that you can create LVs that of a total size that is larger than the VG. The LVs (thin volumes in this case) would then "obtain" blocks from the thin pool as they are being written with data (i.e., have their blocks mapped to the blocks the thin pool).
As time goes by, while whatever uses the thin volumes may have deleted unwanted files in filesystems that resides in the volumes, it does not mean that the blocks "obtained" for those unwanted files are "returned" to the thin pool. Therefore, even if the total size occupied by files that still exist is smaller than the VG, no more blocks can be obtained from the thin pool for creating new files in the thin volumes.
To "reclaim" such "used but unused" blocks for the thin pool, you'll need to "discard" the corresponding mapped blocks on the thin volumes. If the thin volumes are used as virtual disks in your VMs, you should allow discard in the disk setting in each VM, and run fstrim accordingly in the VM (assuming the guest OS is Linux). For volumes that are used directly by the proxmox host (i.e. formatted directly and mounted there), obviously you should run fstrim in proxmox instead. (Note that fstrim work through mount points, so don't expect fstrim -a to have effect on unmounted partitions / thin volumes.)
Obviously the way to automate such action would be to enable the fstrim.timer (or anything equivalent on non-systemd distro) or mount filesystem with the discard option. (If the OS is not Linux, just make sure "TRIM" is "enabled" through whatever equivalent way.)
And I think as long as the used space (which you may try to reduce through discarding) of the thin pool (which is the total used space of the thin volumes) is smaller than the current size of the VG minus size of the new PV (sdj), you should be able to get myself back to a state where the lvg doesn't contain the new drive by using vgreduce. (You may need to shrink the thin pool manually first. I don't really know what exactly would happen when you lvconvert --repair a "full" thin pool. Maybe it would automatically extend it. Either way it should be safe to just try running vgreduce first and see.)
You can use lvs to find out the current usage (Data%) of the thin pool.
P.S. perhaps you never wanted thin pool/provisioning but that was just proxmox default approach; I have no idea whether there's a simple way to move the thin volumes out of the thin pool, i.e. make them "thickly provisioned", while at the same time keeping their data intact.

Also, it's possible to fstrim a container file systems, use pct fstrim for that.

Okay - I ran fstrim -a and .. maybe it worked, I'm not sure. I'm down to 80% on data. I tried to pvmove -n data /dev/sdj /dev/sdk3 and it's failing due to not enough extents available. What now? Seems like fstrim isn't doing what I expected.

@Harv note ... minus size of the new PV (sdj), i.e. current vg size * 0.8 needs to be smaller than the "desired vg size" (i.e. size when without sdj). And again, very likely fstrim -a on the proxmox host (in case that's what you meant) is NOT what you need. See my notes regarding thin volumes as VM disks and @NikitaKipriyanov's comment regarding containers. Without knowing how exactly the thin volumes are used, we cannot tell exactly where you need to start the discard from, and in some setup, you may even need to do it manually at multiple layers.

@TomYan Yeah the thin pool is on the proxmox host, so I believe running it there is what I needed to do.

@Harv of course / I know the thin pool is on the proxmox host. the question is, how are the thin volumes used? (Btw though, I have been assuming that not all the mapped blocks of the thin volumes are used. If now the total size of the "needed" data is actually larger than the original VG size, then discard is not going to help, and in that case you need another disk.)

@Harv Also, I don't think it makes sense to pvmove -n data /dev/sdj /dev/sdk3. I think you should either just shrink the thin pool (first) (lvreduce), or you simply shrink the VG with vgreduce and see if it automatically shrink the thin pool for you. (With pvmove you would be trying to retaining the "new" thin pool size, which is NOT what you want.)

@TomYan $ sudo vgreduce -a pve results in it showing both pv's in use. I'm nervous about using lvreduce - not sure it won't clobber my data, that's why I was trying to use pvmove - I wanted to get data off the one pv and onto the other before removing the unused pv. The good news is I used fstrim in the VMs as you suggested and I'm now down to 60% from 80% on the vg. How do I use lvreduce to safely lower the lv size, and by how much? Is it simply a matter of passing -r, and by the size of the 2nd pv?

@Harv I'm pretty sure lvreduce won't clobber your data, as long as you DON'T use it on the thin volumes, but only the thin pool. by how much Well, you may derive/obtain the desired/original size by checking pvdisplay -m, I suppose. There you can see the extent range(s) of the thin pool. You can get the size of each range with (range end + 1 - range start), and the desired thin pool size would be total size all the ranges of the thin pool except the one on sdj. (For size in MiB, multiple the size in number of extents with pe size.)

@Harv there may or may not be easier (i.e. no calculation) way to do it; you can try --devices in lvreduce if you like; I don't know if listing all the PVs used by the thin pool but sdj would allow you to automatically shrink it with -l 100%. (Again, I suggest trying vgreduce directly first.)

@Harv Note that as per the warnings you posted, it does seem like you need to lvremove pve/data_meta2 and pvmove pve/data_tmeta. (If you wish to retain pve/data_meta2, just shrink the thin pool "further" (how much depends on the size of pve/data_tmeta) so that there will be extents available on e.g. sdk3 for pve/data_tmeta.)

@TomYan Very helpful, thank you. I'm going to try your suggestions tomorrow when I'm not tired and bound to make a catastrophic mistake.

@TomYan I ran fstrim across the board including Windows to get data usage down, but I'm still not sure how to get where I need to. I understand in theory the next step is to get the size of the LV down below the allocated part of the 2nd PV and then instruct it to remove the PV entirely.. but I haven't been able to do that. I've posted command outputs to show my current state. Are you able to add any clarity?

@Harv I think pvdisplay -m would help better. Besides, have you at least run vgreduce and see if it allows you to remove /dev/sdj from the VG?

@TomYan added. Yes, I tried vgreduce but it said the pv's were in use.

@Harv as you can see, you still have /dev/pve/lvol1_pmspare that is 2077-extent long on sdj, while there are only 2017 free extents on /dev/sdk3. Therefore you'll need to shrink your thinpool further by at least 60 extents, so that you can pvmove /dev/sdj. (You can probably opt to delete /dev/pve/data_meta0 and/or /dev/pve/data_meta1 instead. They are probably just backup of /dev/pve/data_tmeta. I'm not entirely sure about it though.)

@TomYan I suspect you're correct about data_meta0 and data_meta1. Any way to verify that these are safe to delete? I ran thin_check on both of them and they both have issues, wheras /dev/mapper/pve-data_tdata can't be checked because it's in use.

I removed data_meta0, data_meta1, ran pvmove for data_tmeta from /dev/sdk3 to /dev/sdj to get contiguous free space, then pvmove /dev/sdj /dev/sdk3 to move it all back.

@Harv you don't need really need contiguous free space for anything; anyway, so now you should be able to vgreduce? Or do you mean you have succeeded?

@TomYan succeeded. Now I guess I'll have to move away from thin pools or otherwise figure out how to never let this happen again.. thank you so much for your help.

@Harv well, thin pool allows you to create thin volumes of total size that is larger than the pool size. If you do not do so, then you should never bump into such problem (but of course then you'd be suffering from the performance impact thin provisioning might have bought without enjoying the benefit).
